# Understanding Arrays in Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Rephrasing my question because I broke it down simpler than I actually did it :-P

I'm still trying to get the hang of relationships between objects and arrays.

I am trying to work on playing with an object full of arrays and I'd like to find the length of arrays in my object, but the way I'm going about it is not working.

```
var patterns = {
    a: [2, 4, 12, 14],
    b: [2, 4, 8, 12, 14],
    c: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14],
    d: [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14],
    e: [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14],
    f: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
};
for(var pattern in patterns){
    console.log(patterns.pattern.length);
}
```

So what is a better...nay, the actual, way I'm should do this?  And for the sake of learning, what is wrong with what I did?

Comment: "I want to say `patterns.c.length` but I know that's wrong" you obviously never tested it because that's the right way to access the length of the `c` array within `patterns`.

Comment: `patterns.c.length;` ?

Comment: Took my 3sec to test...
open the console, copy paste

Comment: Yea, I didn't test it so simply and I should have, what I actually tried to do I wrote below as a response to claudiu's answer...so I guess my trip-up isn't in trying to get the length, it's trying to get the length the way I did.

Comment: @leilanimanani: aye. generally when asking a question, either post what you're doing directly, or at least check that your simplification exhibits the same bug. if it doesn't but you thought it would then you're a step closer to figuring the error out on your own!

Comment: @Claudiu:  Thanks!  It was my first question post in stackoverflow and I learned very quickly that these posts bite you in the butt if you don't ask it right!

Answer (score 2):

How do you know `patterns.c.length` is wrong?

```
> var patterns = {
    a: [2, 4, 12, 14],
    b: [2, 4, 8, 12, 14],
    c: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14],
    d: [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14],
    e: [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14],
    f: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
};
> patterns.c
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
> patterns.c.length
7
```

Comment: Damn, haha, I didn't try it in it's simplest form.  Perhaps I should re-explain my scenario and see what is wrong.  I actually tried to get the length of all of the arrays in this fashion:
for(var pattern in patterns){console.log(patterns.pattern.length)} and it bit me back with errors

Comment: @leilanimanani: In that case you should use bracket notation: `patterns[pattern].length`.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much @go-oleg!  That was the problem.